# Can't locate object method XX via package "1"

Tags: perl

I am well aware that there are several questions on a similar subjects but I fail to see how to apply the answers to my problem :
< Can't locate object method "idx" via package "1" >

What I don't understand is that I am using the same architecture in two packages and that it is OK in the first one... Where is the package "1" coming from ?

Here is the package that works fine :

```
package ObjA;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;
use ObjB;

#CONSTRUCTOR AND INITIALISATION
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {@_};
    bless($self,$class);
    $self->language();
    return $self;
}
sub load {
    my $self = shift;
    open (my $stream,"<",$self ->{name});
    my @glob_xs=();
    my $i = 0;
    while (<$stream>){
        $i += 1;
        my @x = extract($stream,());
        @glob_xs=(@glob_tokens,@x);
    }
    $self->tokens(\@glob_xs);
}

sub extract{
    my ($stream,@x) = @_;
    my $line = <$stream>;
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^\s*$/){
        return @x;
    }
    print join("/",split("\t",$line));
    my $b = ObjB::new(split("\t",$line));
    push @x,$b->form;
    extract_sentence($stream,@x);
}

# OBJECT ACCESSOR METHODS
sub language {$_[0]->{language}=$_[1] if defined $_[1] ; $_[0]->{language}} 

1;
```

And here is the one that produces the error :

```
package ObjB;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp;

# CONSTRUCTOR AND INITIALISATION
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {@_};
    bless($self,$class);
    $self->idx();              # Dies here.
    return $self;
}

# OBJECT ACCESSOR METHODS
sub idx {$_[0]->{idx}=$_[1] if defined $_[1] ; $_[0]->{idx}}
1;
```

Would it be because ObjB is called inside ObjA ? Or because they are declared in two different files ?

I truly hope someone will have an answer because I have been running in circles ...

Thank you !!

Comment: `ObjB::new` looks suspicious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Obj::new` is a method, but you call it as a subroutine.

```
ObjB::new(split("\t",$line));
```

This results in the value of first field of the line being used as the class, and that value is probably `1`. You probably meant to use

```
ObjB->new(split("\t",$line));
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, it worked fine !! (But I still don't understand the subtlety : I used ObjA::new() in the main file of the project and no error was raised... Is it a difference of context main vs. class ?)

Comment: A couple of errors combined to happen to give the right result. `ObjA::new()` is wrong, but since you didn't pass any arguments, `$class` ended up `undef`, and `bless` took that to mean you meant the current package (`ObjA`). In other words, `ObjA::new()` happend to be equivalent to `ObjA::new('ObjA')`, which happened to be equivalent to `ObjA->new()`. But that's not always the case; you just got "lucky".

Comment: Thank you, it is nice to have the explanation with the solution, I get it now!! (That's all me : short-term lucky...)

Comment: @ikegami, is this the same as "indirect object notation"? I'm not in a position to test right now and don't want to forget to find out. If so, OP should google that phrase. If not, it's worth reading about anyhow.

Comment: @stevieb No, `ObjB::new` is just a regular subroutine call. `new ObjB` is [indirect object notation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot,  I thought so. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @stevieb, Indirect object notation is an alternate syntax (you should avoid) for method calls. `method $i @args` is the indirect version of `$i->method(@args)`.